# Global variable is not updated

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, scope

I'm new to `coffeescript`. And I fell into the pit of the JavaScript's variable scope.

I'm trying to develop simple console script with `node.js`, no classes (yet), minimum functional programming sugar (yet). Here it goes:

```coffee
fs      = require 'fs'
code    = "test"

fs.readFile 'COD99000430.TXT', (err, contents) ->
    code = contents.toString()

console.log code
```

it compiles to following JavaScript:

```js
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.3.3
(function() {
  var code, fs;

  fs = require('fs');

  code = "test";

  fs.readFile('COD99000430.TXT', function(err, contents) {
    return code = contents.toString();
  });

  console.log(code);

}).call(this);
```

The issue is that after running that code console shows only word `test`, which is obviously initial value of the `code` variable. But I expect to see contents of the `COD99000430.TXT` file. And actually I can see it, if i put `console.log code` inside of the scope of the anonymous callback function in the `fs.readFile` call.

I've look at [coffieescript documentation](http://coffeescript.org/#lexical_scope) and there exactly the same case was described. But for some reason it does not work for me.

I'm using `node.js` version 0.8.2 on Windows 7, `coffeescript` version 1.3.3.

Is it possible to have "global script" variable in my case? How I can achieve this via coffeescript?

Comment: This has nothing to do with variable scope, or coffeescript at all, really. It's about callbacks, and javascript single-threaded event loop. The callback you supply to `fs.readFile` will be executed when the file contents have been read. The code following `fs.readFile` will be executed immediately after calling `fs.readFile`, i.e. before your callback has been executed.

Comment: Oh... I see... Welcome to `node.js`... Thank you for clue!

Comment: @shytikov It is not about node.js, it is about javascript and asynchronous operations.

Comment: More about getting used to asynchronous thinking at all, I would say. Old shell script writer should change his attitude.

Answer (score 1):

The comments on your question are correct, I just thought I'd provide some working code.

Example 1: Simply log the file contents in the `fs.readFile` callback.

```
fs = require 'fs'

fs.readFile 'COD99000430.TXT', (err, contents) ->
  console.log contents.toString()
```

Example 2: Factor the file processing code into a function and provide a callback to print the contents.

```
fs = require 'fs'

processFile = (filename, callback) ->
  fs.readFile filename, (err, contents) ->
    callback contents.toString()

processFile 'COD99000430.TXT', (data) -> console.log data
```

Comment: hm... First example I've tried before, and it works. But the second one, I was not aware about `callback` keyword. Is it from CoffeeScript or JavaScript? Could you please provide me link to documentation? I was trying to find something, but it seems that search results are messed with `callback` functions..

Comment: @shytikov: No, `callback` is not a keyword. It's just a parameter, just like `filename` in the example. You might just as well call it `peter` -- but it's customary to call it `callback` or `next`.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code a bit so I could get it running in jsfiddle (had to ditch node since it isn't installed on this machine). I think what you need to is change the readFile line to be a function, then call the function later.

```
code = "test"

read = (err, contents) ->
    code = "XZY".toString()

console.log code
alert(code)

code = read()
alert(code)
```

Global variables are considered 'to be avoided'. The coffeescript page that you linked to does have an alternative though:

> If you'd like to create top-level variables for other scripts to use,
>   attach them as properties on window, or on the exports object in
>   CommonJS. The existential operator (covered below), gives you a
>   reliable way to figure out where to add them; if you're targeting both
>   CommonJS and the browser: exports ? this